# How to merge two objects and keep count

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a Rails 5.2 app.
In this app I am working with statistics.

I generate two objects:

```
{
    "total_project": {
        "website": 1,
        "google": 1,
        "instagram": 1
    }
}
```

And this:

```
{
    "total_leads": {
        "website": 1,
        "google": 2,
        "client_referral": 1
    }
}
```

I need to merge these two objects into one single objects that increases the count. The desired result is:

```
{
    "total_both": {
        "website": 2,
        "google": 3,
        "instagram": 1,
        "client_referral": 1
    }
}
```

I tried this and it technically works, it merges the objects but the count is not updated:

```
@total_project = array_projects.group_by { |d| d[:entity_type] }.transform_values(&:count).symbolize_keys
        @total_leads = array_leads.group_by { |d| d[:entity_type] }.transform_values(&:count).symbolize_keys
        @total_sources = merged.merge **@total_project, **@total_leads
```

**Please note that the attributes (sources) are dynamic from the database so I cannot hard code anything. The user can add their own sources.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@total_sources = @total_project.merge(@total_leads) do |key, ts_value, tp_value|
  ts_value + tp_value
end
```

If there can be more than 2 sources, put everything in an array and do.

```
@total_sources = source_array.reduce do |accumulator, next_source|
  accumulator.merge(next_source) { |key, v1, v2| v1 + v2 }
end
```

Comment: If `@total_project` is the result of the OP's calculation neither it nor your code produces the required hash having a single key `:total_both`. In the second part of your answer, if `source_array` is an array containing the two hashes given in the question the result of your calculation is `{:total_project=>{:website=>1, :google=>1, :instagram=>1}, :total_leads=>{:website=>1, :google=>2, :client_referral=>1}}`, which is incorrect. That's because `merge`'s block is only interrogated when the keys of the two hashes being merged are different, but here `:total_project != :total_leads`.

Answer (score 0):

You may compute the desired result as follows.

```
arr = [{ "total_project": { "website": 1, "google": 1, "instagram": 1 } },
       { "total_leads": { "website": 1, "google": 2, "client_referral": 1 } }]
```

```
{ "total_both" => arr.flat_map(&:values)
                     .reduce { |h,g| h.merge(g) { |_,o,n| o+n } } }
  #=> {"total_both"=>{:website=>2, :google=>3, :instagram=>1, :client_referral=>1}}
```

Note that

```
arr.flat_map(&:values)
  #=> [{:website=>1, :google=>1, :instagram=>1},
  #    {:website=>1, :google=>2, :client_referral=>1}]
```

Had I used [Array#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-map) this would have been

```
arr.map(&:values)
  #=> [[{:website=>1, :google=>1, :instagram=>1}],
  #    [{:website=>1, :google=>2, :client_referral=>1}]]
```

See [Enumerable#flat_map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map), [Enumerable#reduce](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) and the form of [Hash#merge](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that takes a block (here `{ |_,o,n| o+n }`) which returns the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. See the doc for `merge` for definitions of the three block variables (here `_`, `o` and `n`). I have named the first block variable (holding the common key) `_` to signal to the reader that it is not used in the block calculation (a common Ruby convention).